# WPF Messagebox shows Error message

Tags: c#, wpf, messagebox

I'm developing a WPF application and I want to show message box with symbol like information or question. I have written this code:

```
MessageBox.Show("Added Sucessfully","Alert",MessageBoxImage.Information);
```

but it shows an [error/red line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkJYN.png):

> Error:system.windows.messagebox.show(string,string,messageboximage) has some invalid arguments

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have missed the `MessageBoxButton` argument. Try the following:

```
MessageBox.Show("Added successfully", "Alert", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
```

Make sure you are using `MessageBox` from `System.Windows` namespace, not `System.Windows.Forms`.